# What is the relationship between an average of correlations and a correlation for an average of the same variables?

Tags: correlation

I have variables $A, B, C,$ and $X.$ It is common to calculate $r_{AX},$ $r_{BX},$ and $r_{CX}$ correlations; however, sometimes the variables A, B, and C are averaged into one variable, $\operatorname{Av}(A,B,C).$

My question is whether the average of the three correlations, $r_{AX},$ $r_{BX},$ and $r_{CX},$ $\operatorname{Av}(r_{AX},r_{BX},r_{CX}),$ is the same as the correlation between the averaged $\operatorname{Av}(A,B,C)$ and $X,$ $r_{\operatorname{Av}(A,B,C)X}.$

Edit after comments: When I calculate these with my data, the average of correlations (using the Fisher transformations) is lower than the correlation for the average.
$r_{AX}$ = .472
$r_{BX}$ = .556
$r_{CX}$ = .573
$\operatorname{Av}(r_{AX},r_{BX},r_{CX})$ = .535
$r_{\operatorname{Av}(A,B,C)X}$ = .619

Is it possible to calculate one from the other without knowing the individual variables or their correlations? If no, is this relationship reliable, that the average of correlations is always lower than the correlation for the average?

Edit2: I see that I still wrote down the wrong question. The point is: is there a general rule about their relationship?
In a realistic case without specifically designed extremes, e.g. data from validated questionnaires with a response range from 0 to 5, I imagine that the two results are somewhat close to each other most of the time. What I wanted to know is what, if anything, can I infer about the one result if I only have the other.

Comment: Could you say what exactly is giving you trouble?  I imagine you could run these procedures and see for yourself how they turn out, so if you do what is left to be answered?

Comment: Here is a small $(A,B,C,X)$ dataset for you to investigate: $(0,6,6,1),(30,33,3,2),(60,60,0,3).$ You can easily do the calculations in your head.

Comment: Re the edit: look at the dataset $(0,100,0,0),(1,-100,-1,1),(2,100,0,2).$ I find the correlation of $Z=(0,1,2)^\prime$ (the last column) with the mean of the first three columns is nearly zero, whereas the three correlations between the first columns and the last column are $0,0,$ and $1.$ Draw your conclusions.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your input. Your example shows that the average of correlations is not always lower than the correlation for the average. But I still can't draw any conclusions about a general rule about their relationship, or even whether such a rule is possible or impossible. In a more realistic case than this quite extreme one, e.g. with validated questionnaires with response range from 0 to 5, I imagine that the two results are somewhat close to each other most of the time. But what I wanted to know is what, if anything, can I infer about the one result by seeing the other.

Comment: Please edit the question itself to clarify your intentions.